# Gitbook Markdown restarts numbering when a table is added to a numbered list

Tags: markdown, gitbook, numbered-list

I want to add a table to a numbered list. Here is what I have tried:

```
1. first line
2. second line

|head1|head2|
|---|---|
|value1|value2|
3. third line
```

However, the third item will numbered with 1.

How can I put a table inside an item in a numbered list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for this *should* be

```
1. first line
2. second line

    |head1|head2|
    |---|---|
    |value1|value2|

3. third line
```

Indenting the table by four spaces should nest the table inside the second list item.

Unfortunately, GitBook doesn't currently support tables nested in lists as confirmed by [this open issue](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook/issues/794).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use * list to replace the numbered list.